# name resolves doesn't work in chroot for users, but does for root

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chroot, ping, hostname

I've booted a live-cd in order to download, compile and install a few packages on a otherwise working system without actually booting said system.

I've created a build user on the system by issuing `useradd -m -G wheel -s /bin/bash builder`

I then proceed to mounting my partition and a chroot environment:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/luksdev on /mnt
# cd /mnt
# cp /etc/resolv.conf etc
# mount -t proc /proc proc
# mount --make-rslave --rbind /sys sys
# mount --make-rslave --rbind /dev dev
# mount --make-rslave --rbind /run run
# chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

After this, I clone, chown and move into the project to build.

```
(chroot)# git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/lighttpd2-git.git /home/builder/lighttpd2
(chroot)# chown -R builder.builder /home/builder/lighttpd2
(chroot)# sudo -u builder -s
(chroot|builder ~)$ cd /home/builder/lighttpd2/
(chroot|builder lighttpd2)$ /usr/bin/makepkg -s --noconfirm
```

As root, I have no issues performing name lookups, so the `git clone` will work as inteded. But switching to any other user during the build process of this package *(or if I run the `git clone` as non-root)*, I will get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd2.git/': Could not resolve host: git.lighttpd.net
```

So I thought of doing simple `ping` check to isolate the issue. Doing `ping www.google.com` works as `root`, but not as `builder`.
However, doing `ping 8.8.8.8` **works for both** `root` & `builder`.

```
(chroot)# ping -c 1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.22.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arn09s11-in-f164.1e100.net (172.217.22.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=2.03 ms

(chroot|builder)$ ping -c 1 www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known

(chroot)# ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=1.97 ms

(chroot|builder)$  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=1.98 ms
```

logically, I thought it has to do with the name resolutions for the specific user.. But doing:

```
(chroot)# nslookup www.google.com
Server:    8.8.8.8
Name:      www.google.com
Address: 216.58.207.196

(chroot|builder)$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:    8.8.8.8
Name:      www.google.com
Address: 216.58.207.196
```

Both users can do nslookup and shows that `/etc/resolv.conf` is present and works. But pinging a hostname or using any type of name-resolve tasks outside of nslookup/dig won't work:

```
(chroot|builder)$ python
>>> from socket import *
>>> s = socket()
>>> s.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I tried sticking solely to ping to keep things simple.
I've also tried making sure nothing's blocking my ping usage:

```
(chroot)# chown root:root /bin/ping; chmod u+srwx,go=rx /bin/ping
(chroot)# getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep
```

But even then, I'm not allowed to ping using hostnames, but IP's still work.

```
(chroot|builder)$ strace ping www.google.com
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
write(2, "ping: socket: Operation not perm"..., 38ping: socket: Operation not permitted)= 38
```

`/home` and `/root` are not mounted with `nosuid` either. Sadly, this is a VM so I can only supply a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV5f4.png) of it.

Since I'm trying ping from `/home`, I don't see a reason why this would cause the issue either. If I boot into the system, and do the exact same thing with the user I created during the live-cd boot.. I can ping hostnames.

At this point I mainly want to understand why some users can perform ping, lookups etc. And some don't during a chroot environment. I'm not sure where to debug/continue from here on in order to try and fix or understand the underlying problem. A couple of helpful souls over at IRC also tried to give a helping hand but we're all baffled.

### Edit:

I've narrowed it down to the `mount --make-rslave --rbind /run run` being the issue. It's the cause for whatever reason. If I try to `ping www.google.com` after each `mount` command (at the start of the question), it stops right after `/run` is mounted.

[image]

Comment: Which live-cd distribution are you using? Does it possibly have an Linux Security Module in place? Like SELinux or apparmor for instance

Comment: @LL3 Valid question, sadly that is not the case with Arch Linux. Not by default anyway. They do have a audit service tho but that only monitors that I know of.

Comment: Instead of a chroot, what happens if you use `systemd-nspawn` to start a container in it?

Comment: @muru That works. I used `systemd-nspawn -D /mnt --machine test`, seeing as I've never used `systemd-nspawn` I'd greatly appreciate it if I got any pointers if that's the wrong way of doing it. `/run` is empty when doing this with the exception of `systemd` being in there. But it sure works.

Comment: @Torxed that's pretty much how I use it too (except I may add `-b` if I want some service within the chroot to start as well, but you probably don't need it). I gave up on messing around with mounts and networking with chroot and switched to systemd-nspawn because of problems like this.

Comment: @muru I'm starting to feel the pain and understand why you did. I suggest you do a write-up on the solution. I'll mark it as a appropriate answer in a day or two if no one else has an answer to the original problem of why this happens.